# Tex document not building in new computer (fontspec)

Tags: miktex, fontspec, texmaker

I have a resume written in Tex that was working just fine. I had to change my HD drive due to a problem. I installed Miktex 2.9 and TexMaker again and configured the packages to download and install on the fly. I'm using Windows 7 x64

When I build the file now, I'm getting several errors, but the first one is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \str_case:nnn
l.31 {Fontin}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I used this [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cv). I downloaded it again, and out of the box it also doesn't build.

This is the portion of my file which (I think) is generating the error:

```
%FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}
%%% modified for Karol Kozioł for ShareLaTeX use
\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic
]
{Fontin}
%%%
```

I've installed the Fonts in my computer and they're also in the root of the .tex file.

Edit: As asked, here is a sample file that gives the same error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
This is Introduction

\end{document}
```

And here is the .log of the minimal example ([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/maZ0mhCc))

Comment: Welcome! Try to make a complete, small document which produces the error when you compile it. We want a complete document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which gives that error when you compile it so that we can compile it and see if we get the error or not.

Comment: That is, *test* whether that code is needed to reproduce the error. If not, take it out. If so, see what else you can remove and still get the error. Eventually, you'll have a minimal example. That's what you want to post here.

Comment: I'm not willing to  create an account just to view the template. Somebody else may be, though.

Comment: @cfr I've added a sample that reproduces the error. Tell me if you need anything else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK. Thanks. In that case, yes, we'll need the log - preferably the log from compiling the minimal example. Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I'm using XeLaTeX. Should I just paste the whole log? Or a specific part of it?

Comment: We only need the relevant bits ;). If you don't know which are relevant, post it all. If it is too long, you can use a pastebin site. If you think you know what's relevant, try posting that bit here first, by all means. But I wasn't sure if you'd know or not since you indicated you were pretty new to this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new :) I've updated with a link to a Pastebin, since I'm not sure if I really know which part is relevant.

Comment: Is MikTeX completely updated? This looks like a bug. There was a bad bug very recently which should be fixed now, so make sure everything is current. I don't use MikTeX so I can't test, but I'm going to ask in chat. Somebody will know. (Soon, if not already.)

Comment: How can I know if everything is updated? The packages were download on the fly, So I'm guessing you're referring to something else?

Comment: Er ... MikTeX has a facility to update the packages which are already installed. That is, the on-the-fly will get packages which weren't installed, but this enables you to update the existing packages you've got. It is a package manager. Probably a special utility application you open to do the update or otherwise administer your installation. Does that mean anything to you? I'm sorry not to be more precise: if you had TeX Live, I would be of more use. If I had Windows, I might be of more use, too.

Comment: Yep. I'm checking the package manager and the Update tool. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Looks like an old version of `fontspec`. Can you post the full log where the files are loaded (should have lines like `C:\Program files\MiKTeX\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty`)?

Comment: fontspec is not up-to-date. Check that your miktex is really current. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: Thank you. The problem was really the fontspec in the version 2.4c. Weird though. I had just installed everything why does the package installed "on-the-fly" was not the latest version? I also had to install both for User and Admin.

Comment: If someone wants to post it as an answer go ahead, so I can give you guys credit for the huge effort. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating a package (fontspec).